# Setting a Static IP Address Not Connecting?

Tags: networking, kubuntu, 19.04, static-ip

I'm following a tutorial for setting a static IP address for my remote backup server. (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/)

I've followed this set of instructions:

```
network:
        renderer: networkd
        ethernets:
            enp0s25:
                dhcp4: no
                addresses: [192.168.111.27/24]
                gateway4: 192.168.1.1
                nameservers:
                         addresses: [192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8]
        version: 2
```

But now I can't connect to my server and will have to restore its netplan from the old copy I made before making modifications.

Custom SSH Config:

```
Host Scilab
  HostName 192.168.43.245
  Port 45834
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/LesserArkKey
```

When I try to use `ssh Scilab`
I get: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.43.245 port 45834: Connection refused`. This is unusual because this worked before (I have a custom ssh config). I changed the current ssh config to the new IP address (It was 192.168.1.144 previously)

What am I doing wrong and how can I set the IP address to a static one instead of DCHP?

**EDIT 0:** For clarification, the server key-based login works just fine when the server has the default Netplan in place. `ssh Scilab` asks for the encryption key and I give the password, and everything connects. It only gives an error when I try and use the new Netplan. Then nothing works.

These commands all fail as well:

```
sarah@LesserArk:~$ ssh -p 45834 -i .ssh/LesserArkKey 192.168.111.27
ssh: connect to host 192.168.111.27 port 45834: Connection refused
sarah@LesserArk:~$ ssh -p 24 -i .ssh/LesserArkKey 192.168.111.27
ssh: connect to host 192.168.111.27 port 24: Connection refused
sarah@LesserArk:~$ ssh -i .ssh/LesserArkKey 192.168.111.27
ssh: connect to host 192.168.111.27 port 22: Connection refused
```

The server after the netplan change:
[image: Server]
`ifconfig`:
[image: Server ifconfig]

SSHD Config:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port 45834
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
MaxStartups 2
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Protocol 2
```

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the outputs of the commands:
`cat /etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

`cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep "hosts:"`: 
`hosts:          files dns`

```
`networkctl status`:

●        State: routable
       Address: 192.168.111.27 on enp0s25
                fe80::225:64ff:feaf:9fc8 on enp0s25
           DNS: 192.168.1.1
                8.8.8.8
```

`ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Feb 14 09:49 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

**EDIT 2:** /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
192.168.111.27  scilab_comp_0

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Output of `hostname`: `scilab_comp_0`

**EDIT 3:** I made a short video from my computer (Not the server) showing more detail as to what is happening:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqQGas4fs_A&feature=youtu.be

Made a quick video of the IP address conflict here: https://youtu.be/P2rXWvdOM7k
[image: exit]

**EDIT 4:** Output of `telnet 192.168.111.27 45834`

```
sarah@scilab_comp_0:~$ telnet 192.168.111.27 45834
Trying 192.168.111.27...
Connected to 192.168.111.27.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Did some more digging and noticed that I have 2 IP addresses for the server. Here is `ip a`:

```
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:64:af:9f:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.111.27/24 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global enp0s25
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.142/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s25
       valid_lft 78971sec preferred_lft 78971sec
    inet6 fe80::225:64ff:feaf:9fc8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see one is dynamic and one is static. I'm not sure if the static one works or not though or how to get rid of the dynamic one (Since I reverted the yaml to the original config so I can access it remotely for the time being from my computer). Given that our config file states that we only want the DCHP one, where is the static ip address coming from?

Also, I verified that only the `50-cloud-init.yaml` has any effect on the configuration. I added the .DISABLED prefix to the other yaml file we created since it doesn't seem to have any effect.

**EDIT 4:** Better Testing

I've made a better way to test whether or not the server is able to connect. I have two terminal windows logged into the server and one just runs a loop with `while true; do ip a; ping -c3 google.com; date; sleep 10; done`. The other does `sudo netplan try` with the netplan to set the IP address to static.

These are the results:
-Every time the IP address goes static (After I hit enter on the other terminal for `sudo netplan try``, ping fails:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:64:af:9f:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.111.27/24 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global enp0s25
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:64ff:feaf:9fc8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

And every time it returns to using the DCHP IP address (Posed earlier when it had 2 IP addresses), it comes back and reports the information to my PC's SSH shell.

Comment: It's not clear to me that you have configured your server to accept connections on 45834. I can see that you have configured your client. Can you clarify?  The server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is the file I"m asking about.

Comment: @StephenBoston Yes, I have configured the sshd_config file. The key-based login works just fine on port 45834 when I have the default Netplan in place.

Comment: Did you try `sudo netplan try` to validate the configuration before applying it? If it succeeds, then your netplan yaml configuration is accepted and then go for `sudo netplan apply` command. I can see your ethernet device `enp0s25` is up and running with IP address **192.168.111.27** from the output of `ip a` command. Please post the output of the commands: 1. `cat /etc/hosts` 2. `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep "hosts:"` 3. `networkctl status` and 4. `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`. Thanks.

Comment: @Marmayogi Done.

Comment: @SarahSzabo, The static IP is missing from the `/etc/hosts` file. Please run command `sudo gedit /etc/hosts` and insert a line (let us say as 3rd line) `192.168.111.27 <hostname>`. You must replace `<hostname>` with the output of `hostname` command. Also please edit your question and post the output of commands: 1. `hostname` and 2. `cat /etc/hosts`. Please `reboot` your computer and then attempt to connect to internet and report the result. Thanks.

Comment: @Marmayogi I rebooted the computer with the above /etc/hosts, and the command: `ssh -p 45834 -i .ssh/LesserArkKey 192.168.111.27` fails with `ssh: connect to host 192.168.111.27 port 45834: Connection refused
` It doesn't work on port 24 or 22 either. The netplan was applied and the computer rebooted before executing this.

Comment: I assume that your yaml file is `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`. Please run this command `sudo touch /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`. After that run  `sudo netplan try` and check for any errors. Then finally run `sudo netplan apply` command. Does your Ethernet connect to internet? Pleast test `ping -c5 google.com` and check for any packet loss.  Please report. Thanks.

Comment: @Marmayogi Not sure what you are trying for with this comment. The configuration in question is using `networkd` not NM, and also, as `ip a` reports, the IP address is set as configured.

Comment: @SarahSzabo Try with `ssh -v`. That will give a trace through the connection process so we'll have a better idea where the fail is happening.

Comment: @StephenBoston Sorry about my late post. I had to go shopping. I applied the settings again with the file `50-cloud-init.yaml` (That's what file was there when I installed the system) and found that `ping -c5 google.com` failed with an "unable to resolve name" issue. The IP of the server was `192.168.43.245`

Comment: @SarahSzabo DNS issue. Try `ln -sf /run/systemd/resolv/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` and then your `ping` again.

Comment: @StephenBoston Just did that. Now pinging google.com works, but I still can't connect via ssh using `ssh -v -p 45834 -i .ssh/LesserArkKey 192.168.111.27`. Additionally, something strange happened. Initially the fix didn't work, but then I deleted the old `50-cloud-init.yaml`  file and applied the changes with `sudo netplan apply`. Instead of showing the new DCHP address, `ip a` shows:`192.168.111.27/24`. Which is strange. I would have expected a DCHP address since I went back to the old configuration. Now pinging google works. I have no idea if the address is actually static or not though.

Comment: @SarahSzabo How many *yaml files in your `/etc/netplan/` directory? I disable a file by adding a `.disabled` suffix -- but any suffix but `yaml` will do. However I do not think you have a netplan problem.  I see `connection refused` when I try a port that is not open. Auth failures get 'Permission denied'. What do you get with `telnet 192.168.111.27 45834`

Comment: @StephenBoston Just posted the output of `telnet 192.168.111.27 45834` in the most recent edit. It appears to hang after SSH-2.0 for a bit before giving the error message.

Comment: @SarahSzabo Is this key you're using one that you generated on your machine or was it given to you?

Comment: @StephenBoston I generated it on my computer. Then sent it to the server using the typical methods. The server accepted the key and now I can log in with it.

Comment: So all is well now?

Comment: @StephenBoston No, there is still something wrong with it. `ping -c3 google.com` has 100% packet loss when I have the static yaml file set as the netplan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93662/discussion-between-stephen-boston-and-sarah-szabo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the server's netplan configuration for the static IP, you are requesting an IP address in a different subnet than the gateway's subnet. Although netplan can assign that IP to your device, the gateway will not be able to communicate with it.

To fix, request an IP address in the same subnet that is assigned via DHCP. So if the DHCP-assigned address is `192.168.1.15`, set your netplan yaml file like this:

```
network:
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp0s25:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.168.1.111/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
                     addresses: [192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8]
```

If you are not sure of the gateway IP, issue the following while you have a good connection via DHCP :

```
ip route
```

The system will respond with something like

```
 default via 192.168.1.1 dev netdev01 ....
```

In this output, the gateway is identified through the `default via` field.

For simplicity, and to avoid issues arising through DNS and local SSH configuration, you can issue your client SSH request with the literal IP address of the server:

```
ssh sarah@192.168.1.111
```

This is a backup server so it is likely that most of your communication with the server will be scripted so the only *functional* reason to use a hostname is if the IP of the server is *very* likely to change.

Also, for simplicity, I would generate my ssh keys to the default `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` unless there is a strong reason to do otherwise. This makes coding the request more clean and simple. I put the public key to a named file only when I want to store the key outside my local home or if I wanted, for some reason I can't imagine having, to keep different keys for different hosts.